# Timber add widget to global context

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I just registered my custom sidebar

```
function custom_widgets_init() {
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Script area',
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_widgets_init' );
```

I want to use my custom widget to global context. I have separated file to this. So inside this file I have something like this

```
add_to_context('custom_script', new \Timber\Timber(get_widgets( 'sidebar-1' )));
```

and this give me error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_widgets()
```

My question is - how can I do this in right way? What I'm missing?

Comment: Does it work if you use `Timber::get_widgets( 'sidebar-1' )` instead of `new \Timber\Timber(get_widgets( 'sidebar-1' ))`?

Comment: Nope :/ I solve my problem by adding new settings page and then I added it to my global context